# How to delete random caracters that k8S system adds to pods name

Tags: kubernetes

I have a namespace that contains pods like :

vpar-*-x-xxxx-v1-**75bb57b655-ck5wg**
vpar-*-x-xxx-v1-**7f784c94db-fj4q6**
vpar-*-x-xxxxx-v1-**59cb4654c8-n65m2**
vpar-*-x-xxxxxxx-v1-**866b85849b-95mmz**
vpar-*-x-xxx-*****-v1-**75f45c9c6c-nwtgg**
vpar-*-x-xxxxx-v1-**6c957fb6f6-xthbd**

I want to delete the random bold string.

Some help please.

The results should be like this :

pod/vpar-parc-m-engagement-v1
pod/vpar-parc-m-groupe-v1
pod/vpar-parc-m-journal-v1
pod/vpar-parc-m-offre-v1
pod/vpar-parc-m-produit-physique-v1
pod/vpar-parc-m-produit-v1

Comment: did you deploy this pods as a deployment in that case you can't, if you deployed it as a standalone pod this should not happen what exactly is your usecase here

when you deployed the pod as deployment you need to distinguish between 2 different pods of the same type in that case this suffix is added to uniquely identify the same

Comment: Consider reading about deployment  vs statefulsets

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've deployed them using a Deployment. You can't get rid of them. If you want to get the pods with a know (or predictable) name you can use [statefulset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) instead. They will create pods with the same name appending the pod number at the end. For example for the statefulset `my-awesome-app` with 3 replicas the pods will be `my-awesome-app-0`, `my-awesome-app-1` and `my-awesome-app-2`.